# Filtering DateTime field with Date Field using Filter Set

Tags: django, django-filter, django-filters

How do I go about filtering a date time field with just a Date field. 
With the model and filter below

http://localhost:8020/applications/?created=19-07-2017 returns an empty queryset even with records which have date created=19-07-2017 (The created date of the record in datetime

IN MY MODELS.PY

```
Class Application(models.Model):
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

IN MY FILTERS.PY

```
import django_filters

class ApplicationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet)
    created = django_filters.DateTimeFilter( label='Created')

    class Meta:
       model = Application
       fields = ['created']
```

Answer (score 5):

Using contains works.
Use DateFilter instead and specify the date format

```
created=django_filters.DateFilter(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d','%d-%m-%Y'],lookup_expr='icontains'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will result in issues if the timezone of the app is not UTC, as the date field returns the datetime stamp in UTC. This means that if an object has a date in UTC+2, of 2022-07-31 00:30, this will be returned as 2022-07-30 22:30, yielding incorrect results. Instead, we can the field name to return the date, where Django already does the conversion of the date using the specified timezone in the settings.py file. This can be done by using field_name='created__date' rather than lookup_expr='icontains'.

Answer (score 3):

use `contains`

```
    created = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name='created',lookup_expr='contains')
```

maybe also need to  change the dateformat , yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1):

Some of the answers below mention the use of `lookup_expr='icontains'`. Whilst this does work, it will yield incorrect results when the apps timezone is not UTC. This is because the date field returns the datetime stamp in UTC.

The result is that if an object has a date in UTC+2, of `2022-07-31 00:30`, this will be returned as `2022-07-30 22:30`, yielding incorrect results. It will be included in a filtered queryset of date `2022-07-30` and not `2022-07-31` as we expect.

Instead, we can the field name to return the date, where Django already does the conversion of the date using the specified timezone in the settings.py file. This can be done by using `field_name='created__date'` rather than `lookup_expr='icontains'` so that it is timezone aware.

```
created=django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='created__date')
```

Answer (score 0):

in your filters.py write this:

```
import django_filters

class ApplicationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet)
    class Meta:
       model = Application
       fields = {'created': '__all__'}
```

in your url :

```
http://localhost:8020/applications/?created__date=19-07-2017
```